# select option from Bot response

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I am new to API.ai. I want to functionality such that when a Bot response says something to select from various options, user will select one of the options.

e.g.,

```
If Bot response says 'Which type of websites do you want to build?'
Select one of the given options.

1) Static

2) Dynamic

3) One page.
```

I have gone though various helps from  the [documentation](https://api.ai/docs) , but I do not know how to set this up.

Please help.

Comment: which documentation?

Comment: Do you want dynamic options based on condition?

Comment: yes, exactly same

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer :

```
$arr = [];
if ($var == "Which type of websites do you want to build?") {
    $arr[] = "Static";
    $arr[] = "Dynamic";
    $arr[] = "One page";
} else {
    $arr[] = "option1";
    $arr[] = "option1";
    $arr[] = "option1";
}

Html Code:

<select name="website">
    <?php
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: Sanjay,  your help is appreciated. But I want this to be implemented in `API.ai` google's AI Library.